# How to make my IP publicly accessible to make my local Tomcat server public?

Tags: networking, ip, hosting, tomcat

I'm working on my desktop computer. On this machine I also run `Tomcat` for my Java development so that I can visit my local address:

```
 http://192.168.1.1:8080/myapp
```

Now I go to `whatsmyip.com` and get my `IP` lets say it is: `119.56.1.78`

Now what I want is that: I go to another PC (not on my LAN) or any PC around the world connected to Internet and type the following address:

```
http:// 119.56.1.78:8080/myapp
```

this should show me the same page that I can access locally from `http:// 192.168.1.1:8080/myapp`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possibile, did you tried it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
It is called ["Port Forwarding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

119.56.1.78 - is your public [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address).
192.168.1.1 - is your [private IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses) address on the [LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network).

To see how port forwarding is done read this very good and short tutorial with lots of nice pictures:
[*How to Forward Ports on Your Router*](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/)

Answer (score 6):

You need to do forward your `8080 port` through your router.

If your `IP` changes (you have a dynamic `IP` or a static `IP`, this is determined by your `ISP`) you can get a host name from [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.org) and set up your router to update `dyndns` with your new `IP` when it changes. this will allow you to access your application like so:

```
hostname.dynsns.org/your_app
```

---

Alternatively, you can rent a hosted server and a domain name.

Answer (score 5):

If it is for *short term*, you can use `localtunnel` (same like `ngrok`).

Just follow these steps (require: NodeJS):

1. Install `localtunnel` by running

   ```
   npm install -g localtunnel
   ```
2. Assumes, your app is running on `http://localhost:8080/`, then run

   ```
   lt --port 8080
   ```

   It will create a public url domain with a random name like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsscq.png).

Note: You can create custom url as well (eg: `lt --port 4200 -s "sangeeth"`, `-s` means *subdomain*).

Ta-da! It's done!

Comment: Cool! But what if my local address is 192.168.1.25:80? can I still use lt?

Comment: visitors have to enter password which I should provide, not convenient for testing webhooks

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @KernelMode answer, using **ngrok** but if you are on a macOS, open a terminal to the directory you downloaded ngrok and type `./ngrok http 8080` this will give you a **http** and a **https** public URL that you can use to access your localhost from other machines:

[image]

Below is a brief info about ngrok and things it can do with examples:

[image]

Note: if you want to access a particular link in your local server, no need to pass that as a command parameter in the terminal, once URL is assigned just append the sub-section to the URL.

For example: Assigned URL: http://1234567890.ngork.io and section you want to access: http://1234567890.ngork.io/myAppSub-section

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [*ngrok*](https://ngrok.com/download).
2. Run your service.
3. Assuming your tomcat server listen on port 8080, run *ngrok* in command line with this command:

> ngrok.exe http 8080

*ngrok* starts port forwarding and it looks like this:

[image]

Now, the client can run request with the url `http://a9bb8562.ngrok.io/myapp`.

Comment: is ngrok able to handle production traffic? let say handling concurrent request before tunneling it to our network

Comment: I don't use this approach for production, only temporary for POC. In my example, it is just a local executable that is not managed, has no scale and no resiliency, so I don't think you should use it as-is for production.

Comment: Do not use this approach for production. This is only for local server testing on your own private machine. If you need to do this for production you need to use a DNS server like Cloudflare or whatever other services you prefer.